# Barcode Reader Code in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, barcode

***Objective...***

I want to add the ability for our condo association to scan bar codes on (UPS, USPS, FedEX, etc) packages as they arrive and post the information to SQL server for later use.

The code could be desktop or web based, but preferably as c# code - .Net 4.5 is Ok.  Any suggestions as to hand scanners also appreciated.

Can anyone suggest a starting point?

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance.

Comment: Well, most USB barcode readers can act as a keyboard replacement, and send normal keystrokes which you can capture in a textbox or whatever.  I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, I really know nothing about bar codes. However, if I read your response correctly, you may have answered it. From your comment, the actual reader sends the information and I merely need to collect it - is that about right?

Comment: That's right, the reader does all the dirty work. You'll just have to look into barcode standards (there's a lot of them) to see whether your reader supports those you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pqScan [Barcode reader](http://www.pqscan.com/barcode-scanner/), it can be used in .net 2.0+, so you can build winforms and asp.net web application with it.